# Recapturing + on Natural numbers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Consider the (multiplically written) *free commutative monoid* $M$ on a countably infinite set $\mathcal P$ of generators (it is isomorphic to $(\mathbb N,\cdot)$ with the primes as generators, $\mathcal P:=\{2,3,5,7,11,13,\ldots\}$).

**Q1:** Are all those commutative, associative $+$ operations described on $M$ somewhere in the literature which satisfy the distributive law ($(a+b)m = am+bm$)? We can restrict first to the *cancellative* $+$ operations.

**Q2:** Is it true that each of these can be obtained by some automorphism $M\to M$ (i.e. using a permutation $\mathcal P\to\mathcal P$)

Comment: What else should your "+" satisfy?  Commutativity, associativity, ...?

Comment: Yes, sorry: commutativity and associativity.

Answer (score 4):

Some examples that are quite different from $a+b$ on $\mathbb N$ are $\min(a,b)$ and $\max(a,b)$, using a partial order on $M$ such that $a \le b$ implies $am \le bm$.

Comment: Thanks, good examples.
Ok, let's say, I wanted "invertible" operation.
Also, I am curious about **all** of these.. :)
Moreover, I am also curious about the $\mathbb N$-type orders on $M$ which are compatible with the monoid structure.

Comment: Note that one such partial order is known under the name "divides", and the corresponding min and max are known under the names gcd and lcm.

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1693969/how-is-this-possible-to-convert-a-long-string-to-a-number-with-less-characters