# Is there any two way algorithm for compressing numbers?

Tags: algorithms, coding-theory, compression

I have this question that is there any way we can convert a number to another number with less character in the new number?

For example, Imagine we have 811008 and if we divide this 13 times by 2, we won't get any point (I mean decimal) and this way will reduce the length of the number (811008)

```
811008/2 = 405504
505504/2 = 202752
202752/2 = 101376
101376/2 = 50688
50688/2 = 25344
25344/2 = 12672
12672/2 = 6336
6336/2 = 3168
3168/2 = 1584
1584/2 = 792
792/2 = 396
396/2 = 198
198/2 = 99
```

So, as you see now 811008 by 13 times of dividing to 2 is 99, it length is just 2 numbers (9 and 9) but 811008 has 6 numbers.

For returning 99 to 811008 we just need to multiply (*) 99 by 2 for 13 times!

I'm looking for an algorithm like this, I know this number is different and I need to comperes a very long number like:

```
385024753664106496204800753664417792221184163840106496204800204800106496131072753664401408139264245760204800106496212992172032753664155648270336303104253952
```

Or even very longer than this.

Comment: In your example you appear to show that $811008=2^{13}\times 99 = 2^{13}\times 3^2 \times 11$.  In general, are you just asking for the prime factorization of your number?  That's doable in principle, of course, but not easy.

Comment: The number in your example is "special". Most numbers are "random" and cannot be encoded like $99\cdot 2^{13}$ or $257!$ in a way that needs essentially less typographical symbols. See here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I found 110 of this number (811008) from 100000 to 999999. but Is it not what do I need, I am looking for an algorithm to compress the number. Thanks for the link

Comment: Universal compression (over a fixed alphabet) is obviously impossible, because then we [could apply it recursively](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1695385/11619). I take it you allow an expansion of the alphabet (the inputs appear to be decimal expansions, but the compressed version also have other symbols, arithmetic operations and such). Anyway, a variant of [Robert Israel's answer to that same question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1695357/11619) shows that there are still elementary limitations as to how much you can do, and Kolmogorov complexity says even more.

Comment: So, are the numbers you want to compress of some specific form?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  Yes I asked before a question and Robert Israel answered to that question and about numbers; Yes, I used 110 numbers from 100000 to 999999 that can be divided 13 times to 2 and don't return decimal. I use each of these for each character, and combine  these together. but I'm looking for a way to reduce its size (I did something, but I need to have less characters) I need your good helps please

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I'm not mathematician; and I found this I don't know really does this work or not! http://lemire.me/blog/2012/09/12/fast-integer-compression-decoding-billions-of-integers-per-second/

Comment: I only had time to look at the beginning. Aren't they compressing a **sequence** of integers (which may be totally different from compressing a single integer, which is how your question came out)? At least when differential coding is used (assuming that the integers are of nearly the same size).